# Quotation software

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a **quotation manager** (i.e. a program to organize and comment textual citations), friendly to the Ubuntu desktop. I found [textcite](http://textcite.sourceforge.net/index.html), but I'd prefer something native to linux. What options do we have?

Comment: Would you be happy with an online manager?

Comment: I don't have a problem with browser-based solutions for specific problems. However in this case I think it is better to have a native program, because I take notes and comment a lot of books, and it'll be stressing to find out that someday the site no longer exists.

Comment: TextCite is a pretty niche kind of software, it will not be easy to find an alternative. I believe that by "native to Linux" you are referring to a QT/GTK GUI. This being a small niche programme, it will always be more interesting its programmer(s) to use a unified code base targeting a portable platform (e.g. the JVM) than maintaining several versions with different interfaces for different systems.

Comment: I don't think it is such a «small niche» provided that there are millions of researchers and students throughout the world which can benefit from such a program. Anyway, I agree on the convenience of a portable platform. However, TextCite is no longer maintained since —at least— 2012, and its age and limitations are becoming evident

Comment: I've checked and TextCite was last update back in 2009

Comment: Are you looking for some tool designed for use with (La)TeX? If so, have a look at `kbibtex` (KDE/Qt).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make use of Zotero for the purpose: https://www.zotero.org

It is a software meant for bibliography managment, but one can add notes and tag the items there.